# How to insert data within a table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to insert a data from a table which has a foreach loop inside. I used to work with webforms so I'm newbie to mvc. I always encountered this scenario in webforms using gridview control and just implement the findcontrol command and it works fine. But in mvc, I could hardly get the solutions how to do it. I already search online but can't find any articles that fits my needs for this type of issue. So far, what I've got is if I insert a data from a first row of the table it will insert the record but if I insert them from the second, third, and so fourth, it will no longer insert the records into my database table. How do I make this perfectly be working?
Heres my model,view and controller to help you resolve the issue. Thanks...

**Model**

```
public class CommentModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Don't miss to put your name.")]
        public string name { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Don't leave your comments empty.")]
        public string comment { get; set;}


    }

    public class ReplyModel
    {
        public int idrep { get; set; }
        public string namerep { get; set; }
        public string reply { get; set; }
    } 

    public class CreateViewModel
    {
        public CommentModel CreateComment { get; set; } // this line is optional
        public ReplyModel CreateReply { get; set; }
        public List<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
        public List<ReplyModel> Replies { get; set; }
    }


Repository:

  public class ReplyRepository
    {
          private ProfileDataContext3 Reprepository;

          public ReplyRepository()
        {
            Reprepository = new ProfileDataContext3();
        }

          public IEnumerable<ReplyModel> GetAllComments()
          {
              List<ReplyModel> profiles = new List<ReplyModel>();
              var prof = from profile in Reprepository.RepTabs
                         orderby profile.Id descending
                         select profile;
              var user = prof.ToList();
              foreach (var item in user)
              {
                  profiles.Add(new ReplyModel()
                  {
                      idrep = item.Id,
                      namerep = item.Name,
                      reply = item.Replies

                  });
              }
              return profiles;
          }
          //declaring methods for inserting records
          public void InsertReply(ReplyModel profile)
          {
              var details = new RepTab()
              {
                  Id=profile.idrep,
                  Name = profile.namerep,

                  Replies = profile.reply

              };

              Reprepository.RepTabs.Add(details);
              Reprepository.SaveChanges();
          }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult PostComment()
        {

            var vModel = new CreateViewModel();

            vModel.Comments = comrepository.GetAllComments().ToList();
            vModel.Replies = replyrepository.GetAllComments().ToList();
            return View(vModel); 
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult PostComment(CommentModel com,string butname, ReplyModel rep)
        {

           switch(butname)
            {
                case "Post Comments":
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                comrepository.InsertComment(com); //this is to insert the records


            }
            //this is to display the records inserted
            var vModel = new CreateViewModel();

            vModel.Comments = comrepository.GetAllComments().ToList();
            vModel.Replies = replyrepository.GetAllComments().ToList();
            return View(vModel); 

                case "Post Reply":
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                replyrepository.InsertReply(rep); //this is to insert the records


            }
            //this is to display the records inserted
            var vModel2 = new CreateViewModel();

            vModel2.Comments = comrepository.GetAllComments().ToList();
            vModel2.Replies = replyrepository.GetAllComments().ToList();
            return View(vModel2); 

                default:
            return null;

           } 

        }
```

**View**

```
@model  MyFirstMVCApp.Models.CreateViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PostComment";
}

<h2>Post Comment</h2>

<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostComment", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary("Unable to Post Comment. Please correct the errors and try again...")

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CommentModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
           <label for="name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

       <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
       <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="comment">Post your Comment here:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
      <textarea id="comment" name="comment" style="width:500px;height:100px;resize:none" ></textarea>
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="comment" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Post Comments" name="butname" />
             @Html.ActionLink("See Comments", "DisplayComment")
        </p>
        <br />

    </fieldset>
}

   <br />
    <h2>Comments</h2>
     <br />

       @using (Html.BeginForm("PostComment", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{   
      <table>     
@foreach (var item in Model.Comments)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="editor-field" style="display:none;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px">

           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreateComment.Id)
        </div>

         <div style="font-weight:bold;">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name) </div> 

  <p style ="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :500px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comment) </p>
  <p style="margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:0px"> <input type="button" id="like" name="like" value="Like" style="color:blue;border:0px;background-color:inherit;cursor:pointer" /> <input type="button" id="Reply" name="Reply" value="Replie(s)" style="color:blue;border:0px;background-color:inherit;cursor:pointer" /></p>

          <div id="divrep" style="position:relative;left:50px; overflow:auto;margin-top:0px">
             <table>
              @foreach (var item2 in Model.Replies)
              {
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                     <p style ="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :445px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.reply)  </p>
                           <br />


                   </td>
                 </tr>
              } 
            </table>


         </div> 
             <input type="text" id="idrep" name="idrep" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Id)" />
       <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="idrep" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                         <br />
           <input type="text" id="namerep" name="namerep" />
       <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="namerep" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                         <br />
              <textarea id="reply" name="reply" style="width:500px;height:100px;resize:none" ></textarea>
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="reply" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

    <br />
           <input type="submit" value="Post Reply" name="butname" />

        </td>


    </tr>

}

</table>


      }
<br />
<br />
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>



@section scripts
{
     <script type ="text/jscript"  src="JQuery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"> 
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('body').keypress(function(e) {
       if (e.which == 13) {
          $("input[value='Post Comments']").trigger('click');
       }
    });

        </script>
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to follow your problem description. Can you simplify it (break the statements in paragraph, highlight code where you have problem, etc)?

Comment: If you look at the view, you can see there the part where you can post a reply with in the table which has a foreach loop. My problem is it will not save a data if you are entering it on second row and so on of the table.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you are displaying a collection of comments, and for each comment you are displaying its collection of replies, and that you want users to be able to (1) add a new comment, and (2) to be able to add a new reply for each comment?

Comment: Perfect,you are exactly right!...so my problem is I cannot save a reply into my database table if you enter it starting from the second row and so fourth.It will just return a null value

Comment: The problem is the naming of your controls, you have multiple controls with the same name and the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind the first one (i.e the first row) and ignore the rest.

Comment: Can you give me any idea on how to handle this multiple control names in respect with my DefaultModelBinder so it won't ignore the rest?

Comment: I'm stuck on how to change the name of the control as per row increments in the table and find that particular control in a certain row based on their index. Unlike in webforms after you declare the index of the row as integer you just have to implement the findcontrol command and it will perfectly capture the values entered in any rows of the table.

Comment: Well you cant easily, not the way you are currently creating the view. Sorry, but almost everything you are doing here is bad and you should ditch it and start again and using jquery to post your comments and update the view.

Comment: So you mean I can save records into my database using jquery?

Comment: I guess using jquery or javascript are the best options to save my reply into my database.I'll try this thanks.

Comment: I'll post an answer shortly with a suggested approach using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the naming of your controls, you have multiple controls with the same name and the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind the first one (i.e the first row) and ignore the rest. I suggest a different approach using jquery to post new comments and avoid having to refresh the page each time.

View

```
...
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CreateComment.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreateComment.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CreateComment.Name)
    // repeat for CreateComment.Comment property
    <input type="submit" id="post-comment" value="Submit Comment" />
  </div>
}
...
```

Script

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent submission
}

$('#post-comment').click(function() {
  // get values for postback
  var inputs = $(this).closest('div').find('input');
  var name = inputs.first().val();
  var comment = inputs.last().val();
  var url = '@Url.Action("PostComment", "Profile")';
  $.post(url, { Name: name, Comment: comment }, function(data) {
    if(data) {
      inputs.val(''); // clear existing inputs
      // create a new element for the comment and add to the DOM, for example
      var para = $('div></div>).text(comment).appendTo(something);
    } else {
      // display an error message
    }
  }
}
```

and add a similar script for posting replies, except use a class name not id for the button so there are no duplicate id's

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostComment(CommentModel model)
{
  // save the comment and if successful
    return Json(true);
  else
    return null;
}
```

For posting back replies, in your foreach loop, add a hidden input for the respective comment ID and include that in the data to post back to a separate action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostReply(ReplyModel model)
{
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I realize mvc needs more client-side scripting than in webforms.

Comment: Not necessarily, but the way you set up your form just didn't suit what you were trying to do, and in this case it seemed unnecessary overhead to post back everything just for 2 properties, then reconstruct the whole view and return it. A few tips (1) don't use tables within tables, (2) make use of html helpers as per my example - apart from being simpler, the generated html will always be correct, especially the naming and validation data attributes. Finally, your keypress function would have submitted the form when a user pressed enter - what if they were just entering a new paragraph?